# Как правильно сделать циклический сдвиг в одномерном массиве?

Tags: java, массивы

Я новичок в java и у меня возник данный вопрос. Опишу ситуацию: есть двумерный массив типа `int` 9 на 9, и есть метод, который делает циклический сдвиг в одномерном массиве на заданное количество элементов.

Первое что я сделал это инициализировал первую строку двумерного массива числами от 1 до 9.

```
private static final int MAX = 9;
private static int[][] baseTable = new int[MAX][MAX];

for (int b = 0; b < 9; b++) {       

    baseTable[0][b] = b + 1;

}
```

После чего я, сделав сдвиг на один элемент, записал то что получится в 4-ю строчку двумерного массива.

```
baseTable[3] = CyclicShift.shiftLeft(baseTable[0], 1);
```

Но тут и возникла проблема: когда функция возвращает сдвинутый массив и записывает его в 4-ю строчку почему-то сдвигается и нулевая строчка, и они, по сути, просто дублирую друг друга. Как я понимаю, они просто ссылаются на одно и тоже место в памяти, и тут возникает вопрос: почему нельзя таким образом проинициализировать строки в массиве?

Вот код метода `shiftLeft`:

```
public static int[] shiftLeft(int[] a, int iter) {
    if (a != null) {
        for (int m = 0; m < iter; m++) {
            int tmp = a[0];
            for (int i = 0; i < a.length - 1; i++) {
                a[i] = a[i + 1];
            }
            a[a.length - 1] = tmp;
        }
        return a;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

P.S. Проблема была решена сначала полным заполнением всего двумерного массива, а затем сортировкой только тех строк, которых мне нужно, и запись в них же. Но интересует именно механизм работы массива, и то, почему возникает такая ситуация.

Comment: Предположу (предположу!), что это на самом деле некоторая превентивная мера защиты. Переданный массив может быть абсолютно произвольной длины, и, с учетом некоторой специфики, он скорее всего будет довольно большим - лично я довольно часто встречаю `byte[]`, в котором держится целый http-запрос или ответ, в котором может передаваться файл, или даже несколько. В таком случае одно неверное использование может пробить потолок использования памяти и закрашить всю программу просто потому, что jvm физически не может выделить столько памяти.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Тут всё довольно просто. Дело в том, что вы переставляете элементы в том же самом массиве, который и получаете в качестве источника.

Нужно определиться, что же все-таки должен делать ваш метод `shiftLeft():`

- Переставлять элементы в том массиве, который получает
- Или возвращать новый массив, являющийся перестановкой старого.

Сейчас он делает и то, и другое. А еще вместо того, чтобы сразу перемещать элементы на N позиций, он делает N итераций — это не очень производительно.

Вот вариант, который создает новый массив и записывает в него значения со сдвигом, используя созданный как раз для этих целей метод [`System.arraycopy(Object src, int srcPos, Object dest, int destPos, int length)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29)

#### Реализация:

```
public class ArrayShift {

    public static int[] shiftLeft(int[] a, int shift) {
        if (a != null) {
            int length = a.length;
            int[] b = new int[length];
            // шаг 1
            System.arraycopy(a, shift, b, 0, length - shift);
            // шаг 2
            System.arraycopy(a, 0, b, length - shift, shift);
            return b;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

#### Вот как это работает.

**Шаг 1:**

```
array a:    0    1    2    3    4    5
                      ↓    ↓    ↓    ↓
array b:              _    _    _    _    _    _
```

**Шаг 2:**

```
array a:                        0    1    2    3    4    5
                                ↓    ↓
array b:    2    3    4    5    _    _
```

#### Несколько юнит-тестов:

```
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

public class ArrayShiftTest {

    int[] source = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

    @Test
    public void testValid() {
        int[] expected = {2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1};
        Assert.assertArrayEquals(expected, ArrayShift.shiftLeft(source, 2));
    }

    public void testZero() {
        Assert.assertArrayEquals(source, ArrayShift.shiftLeft(source, 0));
    }

    /**
     * На отрицательных значениях метод сломается
     * */
    @Test(expected = IndexOutOfBoundsException.class)
    public void testNegative() {
        ArrayShift.shiftLeft(source, -1);
    }

    /**
     * На значениях выше длины массива — тоже
     * */
    @Test(expected = IndexOutOfBoundsException.class)
    public void testExceedLength() {
        ArrayShift.shiftLeft(source, 10);
    }
}
```

Если про юнит-тесты непонятно будет, спрашивайте.

Также подскажу вам три пункта, которые вы можете улучшить самостоятельно:

1. Сдвиг влево и вправо — одно и то же, можно задавать направление положительным и отрицательным значением параметра и объединить `shiftLeft` и `shiftRight`
2. Если не объединять методы, то нужно что-то делать при отрицательных значениях
3. Необходимо подумать о значениях, превышающих длину массива

Answer (score 2):

Я совершенно не знаю Java, но попробую объяснить, как это мне представляется.:)

Думаю, что данное объявление

```
private static int[][] baseTable = new int[MAX][MAX];
```

задает не двумерный массив, а массив массивов. Поэтому каждый элемент `baseTable[i]` - это ссылка на одномерный массив.

Похоже функция `CyclicShift.shiftLeft(baseTable[0], 1);` действительно сдвигает циклически элементы массивы `baseTable[0]`  и возвращает ссылку на этот же массив, то есть на `baseTable[0]`

Эту ссылку вы присваиваете ссылке `baseTable[3]`

```
baseTable[3] = CyclicShift.shiftLeft(baseTable[0], 1);
```

В результате две ссылки массива `baseTable[]` ссылаются на один и тот же целочисленный массив.