# Как циклически сдвинуть двумерный массив на (N, M) элементов?

Tags: массивы, алгоритм, циклы

Задача циклически сдвинуть двумерный массив `A[W][H]` на целочисленный вектор `(M, N)`, используя минимальный буфер (в одно значение).

Запоминаю значение (0, 0) в `tmp`. Далее в цикле иду назад: кто встанет на место (0, 0) — элемент `(0 - M > 0 ? :W + 0 - M) % W, (0 - N > 0 ? :H + 0 - N) % H` — копирую его в (0, 0). И дальше назад, пока не вернёмся в (0, 0) — круг замкнулся, и тогда из `tmp` вставляем значение в (0 + M, 0 + N).

Не могу сообразить, **как поступать с «сериями» таких петель** — сколько их может быть, в зависимости от W, H, M и N? Как учитывать, скажем, поменяли уже элемент (0, 1) или нужно начинать новую серию?

[Прототип](https://deserter.io/fft/index.html) пишу на JavaScript. Даже [с одномерным массивом](http://jsfiddle.net/sergiks/yhabx8kd/) застрял на вопросе — можно ли быть уверенным, что если серия, начатая от 0-го элемента не обошла все значения, то она точно не захватила 1-й элемент, и надо просто `seed++` и запускать следующую серию от 1?

Comment: я могу знаю два способа, как можно циклически сдвигать двумерный массив. Можете привести хотя бы один пример с реальзными данными?

Comment: это сложно: сейчас всё в стадии прототипа – хочу сдвигать "картинку" спектра FFT изображения. В [библиотеке](https://github.com/wellflat/javascript-labs/tree/master/cv/fft), с которой экспериментирую, эти данные хранятся в одномерном массиве.

Comment: Имейте в виду: спектр будет размазываться без весовой обкатки (хотя бы окном Хэмминга) или удаления линейного тренда выборки. По той причине, что межпериодный скачок по времени даст сильные выбросы по всему спектру.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такой сдвиг легко выражается через одномерный циклический сдвиг, если мысленно "разложить" двумерный массив в линию. Например, построчно.

А алгоритмов одномерного циклического сдвига c O(1) дополнительной памяти - много. Например, циклический сдвиг массива [0, N) на K позиций вправо - это просто зеркальный переворот всего массива [0, N), за которым следуют зеркальные перевороты подмассивов [0, K) и [K, N). Понятно, что зеркальный переворот не требует дополнительного буфера размера более 1.

Еще одну реализацию на основе только последовательного доступа можно посмотреть в описании [std::rotate](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate) (реализация именно алгоритма циклического сдвига линейной последовательности в стандартной библиотеке С++).

---

То, что попытались реализовать вы - это что, что Бентли в "Жемчужинах Программирования" называет ["жонглирующим подходом"](https://books.google.com/books?id=kse_7qbWbjsC&lpg=PA14&ots=DhzZCNBUcw&dq=bentley%20juggling%20approach&pg=PA14#v=onepage&q&f=false). Ваш подход занимается обменом элементов вдоль *циклов*, на которые распадается задаваемая таким сдвигом [перестановка](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0#.D0.9F.D1.80.D0.BE.D0.B8.D0.B7.D0.B2.D0.B5.D0.B4.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.B8.D1.8F_.D1.86.D0.B8.D0.BA.D0.BB.D0.BE.D0.B2_.D0.B8_.D0.B7.D0.BD.D0.B0.D0.BA_.D0.BF.D0.B5.D1.80.D0.B5.D1.81.D1.82.D0.B0.D0.BD.D0.BE.D0.B2.D0.BA.D0.B8).

И, разумеется, распадаться она может более чем на один цикл, т.е. замыкание цикла (возврат в процессе обработки в элемент (0, 0)) совсем не означает, что вы переставили все элементы на свои места. Потребуется выполнить поиск еще не затронутых элементов и снова следовать по новому циклу до тех пор, пока не обработаются все элементы массива. Для этого придется завести какой-то дополнительный буфер флагов, чтобы помечать уже переставленные элементы, что возможно не совсем соответствует требованиям задачи.

Answer (score 1):

Рассмотрим одномерный циклический сдвиг W-элементного буфера на M позиций вправо.
Случай M >= W существует только в воображении, поэтому M < W. Но он показывает, что сдвиг на M позиций вправо равнозначен сдвигу на (W-M) позиций влево (стробоскопический эффект). Это позволяет решить исходную задачу переносом большей части буфера B либо влево, либо вправо.
Т.е.:

1. Запоминаем меньший кусок L (не надо жадничать, ибо выигрыш велик.)
2. Если перенос влево - то в цикле от L до N-1 переписываем каждый i-тый элемент буфера в позицию i-L. Если вправо - то в цикле по убыванию индекса от B-1 до 0 переписываем каждый i-тый элемент буфера в позицию i+L.
3. Свободное место заполняем куском L.

По сравнению с приведённой реализацией - экономия минимум в L раз. И никаких "петель".

А вот двумерность как раз себя особо не проявляет. H сдвигов на W позиций, W сдвигов на H позиций - и всё.

Comment: Нашёл похожее описание одномерного циклического сдвига здесь: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/446169/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B3-%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5?rq=1